# Pyramid job scheduler

Tags: scheduled-tasks, pyramid, python-asyncio

I need to run a background job in my pyramid application, one time every hour. The job work asynch without block the main thread that serve responses to the clients requestes. This job need to access to a database for store information.

How can i do this? What library/package/algoritm I have to use?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyramid_scheduler/0.2.2

Answer (score 1):

This really seems like cron job. So you may create simple python script and execute it via cron.

As another variant you may use [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org) (you also need [pyramid-celery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyramid_celery/) for this)